# what default login credentials used in VM created by powershell command

Tags: azure

I just folow this tutorial
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/quick-create-powershell

to create VM from powershel, however when I try to conenct, what credentials is used to login VM, if not specified before ?

```
 New-AzVm `
>>     -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroup" `
>>     -Name "myVM" `
>>     -Location "East US" `
>>     -VirtualNetworkName "myVnet" `
>>     -SubnetName "mySubnet" `
>>     -SecurityGroupName "myNetworkSecurityGroup" `
>>     -PublicIpAddressName "myPublicIpAddress" `
>>     -OpenPorts 80,3389
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have provided a password or SSH key when you created the VM. The command you listed does not have enough properties to work.

Comment: yes, you have right, there is popup menu to put credentials.